# Auto check if the input box its possible or not

Tags: jquery, input

I would like to do something like this:

http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/validateform/ (Fixed Link)

When you type, jquery automatically verify if its a possible result, if is, appears a message like "Ok", if not, appears a message like "Something is wrong, try again"

I don't have any idea how to do it :/

Comment: Hi Matheus, i'd suggest doing a little research on "input validation with jQuery," trying a few approaches out, and then asking a more refined question on StackOverflow. The good news is, there are tons of ways to do this : )

Comment: use jQuery's `.onkeyup()` method on text box and check the `.val()` of the text box on your conditions, and then show wether it's ok or not :)

Comment: http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

Comment: Like this: http://yensdesign.com/tutorials/validateform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do this. One way is to subscribe to the change event, then do your verification there.

```
<input id="myInputBox" type='text' />
<div id="message" style="display: none;"></div>


$("#myInputBox").change(function() {
    $("#message").hide().removeClass("error ok");
    var verified = false;
    // do verification here logic here
    if(verified) {
        $("#message").text("OK").addClass("ok").show();
    } else { 
        $("#message").text("Try again!").addClass("error").show();
    }
});
```